# How to run simple example from the true terrain addon trial version?

Tags: add-on

I installed the [True Terrain Trial version](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/true-terrain-) from Blender market.

How do I run the trial version?

I'm trying to find an entry point. I look at examples on YouTube, but it does not work at all to run the simplest example

I was looking for True-VFX and true terrain but found nothing

[image: Screenshot of preferences showing trial version installed and enabled]

[image: Screenshot of default scene not showing how to access trial version.]

Comment: That's an (expensive) external addon, not part of Blender, so questions about it are not going to be answered here. Try looking for contact details on the addon page and asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the side panel (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>) and look for the "True-VXF" tab:

[image: Side panel showing True-VFX tab highlighted]

That will take you to a panel where you can find Documentation and Tutorials:

[image: True Terrain side panel]

You can get a quick example by hitting the "Enable A.N.T Terrain" button and then clicking "Add Landscape".